# Create a temp table at run time without knowing the list of columns before hand

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic-sql

How can I create a `temp table` if I don't know the name of columns?  Names of columns I get at run time with some dynamic `pivot` so for example my `DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)` now has a comma separated list of columns like '[First_Name],[Last_Name], [Address], [Phone]' .
How can I create a temp table now that its columns are coming from that list? ( forget about the data type, everything a NVARCHAR(500) is good enough.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have that kind of construct for `CREATE TABLE` Create it on the fly when you select from your pivot.  `SELECT * INTO #tmp FROM...`

Comment: @squillman the part I am confused is the #tmp.  If I don't know what is #tmp then how do you define it before using it in that SELECT statement

Comment: In this instance #tmp gets automatically created with column names and datatypes based on the resultset of your query.  You don't need to know how to define #tmp, you never issue a `CREATE TABLE` statement.  It's created automatically on the fly during the SELECT.  #tmp will be equivalent to your resultset (except for PK, indexes, identity, etc)

Comment: You can dynamically create the `create table` statement at the same time you are building `@cols`. You'll need to create the table directly in `tempdb` as a normal table due to process scoping, taking into account concurrency if relevant.

Comment: Probably would help us explain it better if you post your dynamic pivot.

Comment: it doesn't matter. my question is imagine somehow from somewhere I get a comma separated list that are supposed to be column names. Now how do I convert that into a temp table ?

Comment: We're telling you that you don't need to go through the headache of doing that.  There is a much simpler way to do it.

Comment: If you have a string of column names like shown you can just use functions like `replace` and `concat` to add in the relevant data types and `create table` syntax.

Comment: The problem with creating a temporary table dynamically is that as soon as the dynamic statement's batch ends, the table goes with it. `DECLARE @col sysname = N'MyCol'; DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'CREATE TABLE #tmp (' + QUOTENAME(@col) + N' int);'; EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL; SELECT * FROM #tmp;` will generate the error `Invalid object name '#tmp'.`, as the table has been implicitly `DROP`ed by the time the outer `SELECT` attempts to reference it.

Comment: Honestly, this smells of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: @Larnu Yes indeed that's so, that's why I mentioned creating a "proper" table in tempDB such that this doesn't happen and you can control exactly if and when it's dropped, taking into account a unique name if concurrency is required etc.

Comment: There is probably a better way of doing whatever it is you are doing. If you show us the code you have so far we can see

Comment: @Larnu But you can select from *within* the dynamic SQL obviously. `DECLARE @col sysname = N'MyCol'; DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'CREATE TABLE #tmp (' + QUOTENAME(@col) + N' int); SELECT * FROM #tmp;'; EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;`

Comment: Yes, correct, @Charlieface (I didn't say you couldn't), though I suspect that doing that may be adding additional complexity to a problem the OP is likely already making overly complex.